# Get Heroku environment variable with PHP script

Tags: php, heroku

I can't access my Heroku environment variables when I run a PHP script. On the picture below you can see that I have variable `TEST_VAR`.

[image: create heroku env var]

The code snippet below should output this variable, I get nothing instead:

```
$url = getenv('TEST_VAR');
echo $url;
```

I tried this and got 'Error!', so `getenv('TEST_VAR')` is `false`:

```
if (getenv('TEST_VAR')) {
    $url = getenv('TEST_VAR');
    echo $url;
} else {
    die('Error!');
}
```

In this picture you can see the output of both snippets (empty string and Error!).

[image: output]

Comment: "Code snippet below should output this variable"—yes, it probably should. What is `getenv('TEST_VAR')` returning instead? How are you running this code? Please read [ask].

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Note that you don't need to use HTML in your question. Stack Overflow [supports Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), a simple formatting language that's much easier to type and read.

Comment: Note that your snippet doesn't actually guarantee that `getenv('TEST_VAR')` is returning `false`. [Many other values evaluate to `false` in Boolean context in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). For example, if `TEST_ENV` was set to the empty string I believe you'd get the same result. It's a good idea to use [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or, better yet, use a debugger, to actually see the real value of a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're running that code on your local command line. `heroku config:set` sets [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) *for your app on Heroku*. It doesn't do anything to your local environment.

To use environment variables locally you must set them another way. You could do it manually, using whatever tools your operating system provides, but the Heroku CLI also provides [a `heroku local` command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-local-processname) that conveniently [reads environment variables from a file called `.env` and populates them for you](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#set-up-your-local-environment-variables).

Simply create an `.env` file containing your variables, e.g.

```
TEST_VAR=hello_world
```

and then run your code via `heroku local`. By default this will run your `web` process as defined in your `Procfile`. If you have already set up variables using `heroku config:set` you can [copy them to your `.env` file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#copy-heroku-config-vars-to-your-local-env-file):

```
heroku config:get TEST_VAR >> .env
```

Note that [the `.env` file should not be committed to your repository](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#add-a-config-var-to-your-env-file). It's meant for local use only. On Heroku, you should continue to set config vars using `heroku config:set`.